# Maximum of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let $f : X(\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}$ by the function $f(x,y) = x^ny^m,$ where $D = \{ (x,y) \ \vert \ x^2+ y^2 <1 \}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. I want to determine the supremum of $f$.

We can compute the partials, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = ny^mx^{n-1}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = mx^ny^{m-1}$$ which gives a critical point at $(0,0)$. This looks like a minimum since $f(0,0)=0$.

To determine the supremum, we would need to look on the bound of $D$. This gives us $$f(x) = x^n (1-x^2)^{m/2}.$$ Calculating the derivative of this, $$f'(x) = nx^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{m/2} - mx^{n+1}(1-x^2)^{(m-2)/2} =0 \\
= x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{\frac{m}{2}-1}[n(1-x^2)-mx^2] =0 \ \ $$ which says that $x=0$, $1-x^2 =0$ or $$n(1-x^2)-mx^2=0 \implies n-(m+n)x^2=0 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+m}}.$$ Can we then assert that the supremum occurs at $$\left(\pm \sqrt{\frac{n}{m+n}}, \pm \sqrt{\frac{m}{m+n}} \right)$$ and the supremum is $$f\left(\pm \sqrt{\frac{n}{m+n}}, \pm \sqrt{\frac{m}{m+n}} \right)=\frac{n^nm^m}{(m+n)^{m+n}}?$$

Comment: For completeness, you should add the reasons why the $x=0$ and $1+x^2=0$ cases do not lead to a supremum, but other than that, it looks good to me.

Comment: $f(0,0)$ is not the minimum value if $m+n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: with $AM-GM$ we get for $$x\geq 0,y\geq 0$$
$$(xy)^n\le \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^n<\frac{1}{2^n}$$ for $$x^2+y^2<1$$

Comment: I have edited the question, I want to investigate the behaviour of a function a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the points $(x,y)\in\partial D$ where $(xy)^n$ is maximal. To this end consider the pullback
$$\hat f(\phi)=(\cos\phi\sin\phi)^n=2^{-n}\sin^n(2\phi)\qquad(\phi\in{\mathbb R})\ .$$
If $n\geq1$ is even then $\hat f$ assumes values between $0$ and $2^{-n}$, and if $n$ is odd then $\hat f$ assumes values between $-2^{-n}$ and $2^{-n}$.

If $n$ is even then the critical point $(0,0)$ is a local minimum, and if $n$ is odd then this point  is a saddle point.

In all we can say that $\sup_{(x,y)\in D} f(x,y)=2^{-n}$.

Note that there is an error in your calculation: Replace $\left({1\over\sqrt{2}},{1\over2}\right)$ by $\left(\pm{1\over\sqrt{2}},\pm{1\over\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Comment: I have edited the question, I want to investigate the behaviour of a function a little more complex